# How to properly use plain Bootstrap UI Library ( with its jQuery dependency ) with Angular 2 & Webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have an Angular 2 app with Webpack. I just wanted to add simple responsive styles with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) library.

Since Bootstrap has dependency on Jquery, the order of loading files is important in this case.

I am not sure how to properly specify the dependency order with Webpack & Angular 2.

Appreciate your help in resolving this dependency issue.